# The Size Of A Vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Let the be $v=(a_1,a_2,....a_n)$ a vector in $\mathbb{C^n}$, $\mathbb{R^n}$

We will say that $A \subseteq V$ blocked if there is $M>0$ so for every $v \in A$ the $||v||<M$

What is the largest of elements in a vector space that he is also a blocked group?

I think that because a vector space can be displayed in infinite ways/vectos (even depended ones) the answer is infinite

Comment: Do you mean to ask about what is the largest blocked subspace ?

Comment: the largest size of a vector in the subspace

Answer (score 1):

If $W$ is a bounded subspace of $V$ then $W=\{0\}$. Otherwise there
is some $w\in W$ with $||w||=r$ and for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ the
element $\alpha w\in W$ satisfies 
$$
||\alpha w||=|\alpha|||w||=|\alpha|r
$$

which is arbitrary large since $r$ is fixed hence $W$ is not bounded